# where pull request should be merged? main or dev branch

Tags: git, pull-request

I am learning Git, and I would like to know where the pull requests should be target, to main or dev branch? I mean I create a feature branch locally, add some commits, the I do git push origin feature-branch, then I create the pull request, but this should target the main or dev branch?

I read some articles that you never should push to the main branch, thats why you use pull requests. Also I would like to know if the I am doing ok with a personal project I have, The main project, in production, uses the main branch, and the demo project(which has the new features first), uses the dev branch, both are online, is that approach ok?, thanks

Comment: It's going to depend entirely on how the repo is set up and what the delivery flow for the product is. If you're working on a personal project with no collaboration, you likely don't need PRs at all - who's reviewing them?

Comment: there can be as many branches as you want and you can create pull requests for any branch. Which you choose depends on what your company/team does and your personal opinions. This is inherently an opinion-based question.

Comment: Thanks for responding. For my personal project I am not using  PR. PR is for a new job that I would like to apply.

Comment: @Felipe Then this question is one you need to ask your new employer: what are their PR conventions. There are many possible answers. The one you should use is the one they've decided to use for their projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using "Gitflow" branching model.

There are 2 widely used branching strategies,

1. Gitflow
2. Trunck Based

Gitflow - uses multiple primary branches ( dev, main, ... ). You should use dev branch for all code integrations where developers can merge (pull request) their feature/.., bugfix/.. and on release you should create your release branch based on main and merge dev into release branch. once release done you should update your main branch (merge release branch in main) as post production activity and tag release version.

In Trunck Based - one primary branch gets all merge / pull request with help of feature-flag useful only if it is required daily continuous automated deployment / A/B testing...

Comment: thanks for responding, one doubt, you said this: "and on release you should create your release branch based on main and merge dev into release branch" I don't understand very well, I mean, imagine my pull request was merge into dev, then the team lead pull all the changes, then he creates a release branch based on main? but main doesn't have the changes from dev yet, I assume that he do this: git merge dev, on main. then the create the release branch, is that ok?

Comment: Yes correct. DevOps person (team lead in your case) will do this activity to release where he will create release branch ( example - release/v1.0.0 ) based on main `git checkout -b release/v10.0.0` and then `git merge develop` ( to have all new changes from dev branch ) and release update on production.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the first question - whichever branch you're supposed to use.
depending on your company/team/workflow.

Comment: what if your company/team/workflow does it differently? there is no "always" answer to this question.

Comment: Agreed. So I have written base branch. Terminology of branch can be different.(main/ develop etc)

Comment: there is nothing special about any branch over any other in git. So your answer translates to "whichever branch you're supposed to use." Which is not helpful at all.